# Is it possible to validate an XML Soap Request against an XSD?

Tags: postman

I am using the Crome version of [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) and would like to validate my XML SOAP requests (against an XSD) before submitting them. Is this possible? I can only find support for JSON schema validation.